# How do you organize classes on a large project?

Tags: code-organization, project-organization

We have a ton of features in our application that can be described very concretely as a module.  The usually have some sort of setup dialog, then when the user clicks ok, it configures a process to run and runs that process.  Sometimes they are more involed and the user will open up the new dialog and work on the dialog for a while, doing many things that make changes to the underlying database.

I typically end up with several standard classes

```
ConfigPanel.cs
ConfigPanelData.cs
ProcessRunner.cs
ApiWrapper.cs (for calling the process from somewhere else)
```

If I had a more end to end module it might be
    WorkerPanel.cs
    WorkerData.cs
    SetupOptions.cs (panel state persisted between runs)
    Lib/WhateverBackendStuffINeedToSupportModule
    ApiWrapper

Right now there are folders for each one:

```
UI/Panels/
    Module1Panel.cs
    Module2Panel.cs
UI/PanelData/
    Module1PanelData.cs
    Module2PanelData.cs
UI/PanelManagers
    Module1PanelManager.cs
    Module2PanelManager.cs
Core/Module1/
    Module1.cs
    Module1Helpers.cs
Core/Module2/
    Module2.cs
    Module2Helpers.cs
```

As you can see, everything is really spread out.  With 50+ modules those folders aren't really organized.  Even breaking them up by subsystem, they are still a mess.  Would it be bad design to just put everything together so everything is separated by function rather than class type?

```
Module1/
    Module1Panel.cs
    Module1PanelData.cs
    Module1PanelManager.cs
    Module1PanelLib.cs
    Module1PanelWrapper.cs
Module2/
    Module2Panel.cs
    Module2PanelData.cs
    Module2PanelManager.cs
    Module2PanelLib.cs
    Module2PanelWrapper.cs
```

How do you organize your classes and what are the advantages / disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be bad design to just put
>   everything together so everything is
>   separated by function rather than
>   class type?

There's no general rule, it depends on the situation, your personal preferences and change patterns in your code.
However I would suggest doing the following:

- Keep as much of the common code in the superclasses to eliminate any redundancy. Maybe then some of the subclasses won't even be needed.
- I'm not sure what you mean by "modules", but I would recommend separating the stuff using namespaces+subdirectories in the same project and not by using separate assemblies. Use assemblies only for deployment separation purposes and similar stuff.
- Those "helper" classes you mention sound a bit code-smelly. They could be a violation of OO principles. Check out this link for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/nickmalik/archive/2005/09/06/461404.aspx. Maybe you can reorganize the code, reduce the need for such classes AND get a benefit of a cleaner OO design at the same time?